# is there anything like nodemon that will restart a node app when .ejs file changes?

Tags: node.js

is there anything like nodemon that works on .ejs file changes?

nodemon will detect changes in .js or .coffee files and restart your node app. But it won't detect changes to view files. I've emailed author, but they are unresponsive.

Comment: Is it required at all to restart Node.js when you make changes to .ejs files? IIRC you can change .jade files and the changes reflect immediately in the browser without the need to restart the Node app.

Comment: yes, they are compiled from what i understand. Either way, I definitely get weird things happening if I dont' bump node.

Comment: things not working. if i bump node it works fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use supervisor. https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor or `npm install supervisor -g`

If you need to watch certain files, you just update the -e argument. So you would run something similar to

```
supervisor -e 'js|ejs|node|coffee' app.js
```

Comment: do you use this in production too?

Comment: I'm sure people do use supervisor in production. Although I would probably lean toward Haibu (https://github.com/nodejitsu/haibu), It's an basically an application server for node applications. You can also use Heroku or Nodejitsu in production. They both have lots of technology for keeping node alive.

Comment: `nodemon -e '.coffee|.js|.ejs' app.js`

Answer (score 43):

Maybe this wasn't implemented when you posted the question, but you simply pass the option

```
-e coffee,js,ejs
```

See the docs: https://github.com/remy/nodemon

`supervisor` is an alternative, but when I last used it, it was eating CPU. That may have been fixed by now, but I'd stick with `nodemon`.

Answer (score 11):

use this in your packages.json

```
"scripts":{
"start":"nodemon -e js,ejs,html -w . -w public -w views -w routes -w models server.js"
}
```

Supervisor constantly eats ~20% of my CPU

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Node.js v18 or higher, you can stop using nodemon and just pass the `--watch` flag to the `node` command:

```
node --watch index.js
```

The option is still experimental, but it works fine most of the time.

Comment: can i specify file types like .html, .css etc?

Comment: You can specify the [paths to the directories](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--watch-path) containing the files you want Node.js to watch. I haven't seen an option that allows specifying a file type nor have I tested.

Comment: By default, watch mode will watch the entry point and any required or imported module.

Comment: you can set the path for watch: "node --watch-path=./ index.js" so now will watch any change on all files and subfolders such as ejs, js, css or .env

Answer (score 1):

1. You can wrap ejs with self-written monitor that will watches for file changes and clear template cache.
2. You can change template engine to one that alredy support hot-reloading. I recommend you [ECT](http://ectjs.com). It support automatic template reloading from the box (with `watch` option) and [several times faster](http://ectjs.com/#benchmark) than EJS and many others.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your NODE_ENV=development and use nodemon. It works